# Wordpress меню - как сделать двухуровневое меню

Tags: php, wordpress

Как сделать что бы в двухуровневом меню пункты верхнего уровня тоже были ссылками?
Всё стандартно:

```
    <?php   wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'header_menu_down',
        'menu' => false ,
        'container' => false,
        'container_class' => false ,
        'container_id'  => false ,
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
    ));?>
```

Comment: приведите хоть код, как вы меню вызываете/строете

Comment: Судя по коду выше внутри волкера у первого уровня убираются ссылки для совместимости с бутстрапом